# What is the most general definition of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, multigraphs

I would like to give the most general definition of a graph. Based on what I read about graphs, I came up with the following definition:

> Let us introduce some symbols. They are

> (a) $V$:: a non-empty set of vertices;

> (b) $E$:: a set of edges $E$;

> (c) $\mathcal{P}(X)$:: the power set of a set $X$;

> (d) $\mathit{\Pi}(X)=(\mathcal{P}(X)\cup 
> \bigcup \limits_{i=2}^{\infty}X^i)\setminus \varnothing$:: the alternative power set (with ordered and unordered tuples);

> (e) $F$:: a class of functions defined over any subset of $\mathit{\Pi}(V \cup E) \cup (V \cup E)$.

> The structure $G=(V,E,F)$ is a (general) graph if there is an $I \in F$ with $I: E \rightarrow \mathit{\Pi}(V \cup E)$, which is called incidence function.

Is this a specification which includes all versions of graphs known in the literature (or at least the most important ones)? Can it happen that an even more general definition is needed for some very special graphs?

It would be also interesting if this formalism could be reduced.

Comment: Many do wish to include directed graphs, and perhaps even graphs tagged with numbers to indicate lengths or weights, as graphs. But in my humble opinion there is no reason to build all of this into a single definition, if only because it makes it harder to define simple examples of graphs or check that something is a graph. The more data that has to come along for the ride, the harder it may be to simply talk about things. I'm happy if the definition allows a single edge to have the same endpoints, and different edges to have the same endpoints.

Comment: Are $V$ and $E$ allowed to be empty?

Comment: @user338955 That's an interesting question. Should we allow this?

Comment: Yes, but talking about millions of types of graphs is also not convenient. This definition allows directed-undirected-mixed graphs, simple graphs, multiple graphs, pseudographs, and hypergraphs. If one needs a special graph, they can restrict the incidence function.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the broader the definition of "graph," the more likely it is that theorems about "graphs" will need additional hypotheses that take them out of the world of all "graphs" to make them true. This is mostly an aesthetic thing, however. I prefer a world where an edge has two endpoints. Your definition seems to include that (perhaps with some data that would be trivial or redundant) and so is fine with me. If anybody cares what I think, which they shouldn't.

Comment: There are several scientific applications, like chemical reaction networks, where hypergraphs are needed.

Comment: I think $E$ should be allowed to be empty.  I'm not so sure about $V$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I finally included in the definition. ;) If there is an edge, then it presumes at lease one vertex, a vertex does not require an edge.

Comment: @user338955, I like you. I see where you are going with this. I am fine if they are the same. Call me old-fashioned, but I don't want an edge to have three endpoints. Even if they are all the same.

Comment: In the theory of chemical reaction networks, there may be an edge passing through a, b, c which can be specified with the folloring incidence: (a, a, a, b, b, c, c, c, c). ;)

Comment: I suspect the downvotes (not mine!) are because of your repeated edits.  Some users are annoyed by this.

Comment: OK, I stopped editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general definition that I am aware of is the one of [Ubergraphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05547) which generalize [Hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). And Ubergraphs are not included in your definition.

A hypergraph is a pair $(V,E)$ whereby $V$ is a set whose elements are called vertices and $E \subseteq \mathcal{P}(V)$ is a non-empty subset of $V$ whose elements are called hyperedges. A hypergraph allows more than two vertices in an edge of the graph. Hypergraphs can also be directed, and thus generalizing directed graphs.

An Ubergraph goes one step further by allowing not only more than two vertices in each edge but also other edges. All hypergraphs are therefore just some special ubergraphs. And the usual graphs are some special $2$-hypergraphs. Making both versions directed is usually done by introducing an incidence mapping defining two additional mappings for each endpoint (source, target). How this is generalized to Ubergraphs, I do not know.

Comment: Can an edge of an ubergraph contain itself? If so, then $I$ could map the edges into $\mathit{\Pi}(V \cup E)$.

Comment: OK, then $\mathit{\Pi}(V \cup E)$ should be a good choice for the image set of $I$, because it comprises all the ordered and the unordered tuples of $V \cup E$. So then the definition should work not only for ubergraphs, but also for directed (even mixed) ubermultigraphs. ;)

Comment: Meditating a bit on what you wrote, it seems to me that the definition in the question is a bit more general than ubergraphs. Let $e \in E$ be an edge and let $I(e)=\left[o_1,o_2,\ldots,o_n \right]$ be its incidence, where [] denotes a tuple (ordered or unordered, it is does not matter), and $o_i \in V \cup E$ (note that the $e$ edge is not a set, but 'only' an object in $E$). Then, for example, $I(e)=\left [e,v', e', v'', v''', e'' \right ]$ is also allowed, where $e'$ and $e''$ are edges, while $v$', $v''$ and $v'''$ are vertices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119809/discussion-between-david-scholz-and-tobir).

Comment: After a short private discussion, I now understand that if $I$ is a function (that is, a set in ZFC sense), then incidences like $(v,e)$ are forbidden for an edge $e$.

Answer (score 0):

Common definition is that a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a finite set of *vertices* $V$ and a set of *edges* $E$, where an edge $e \in E$ is a set of exactly two vertices.
Some allow an infinite set of vertices.

The other stuff (neighbors of $v$, and so on) can be deduced from this.

Note that digraphs (directed graphs) $D = (V, E)$ add a significant difference: The set of edges is a set of pairs of vertices, $E \subseteq V \times V$. They are very different beasts.

Comment: What about loops? Your graph definition would allow them if you did not restrict the entries of E to have two vertices.

Comment: Loops are best represented by having the same vertex associated twice with one edge, rather than having a different kind of edge for loops. That then keeps the relationships between edges and degree values consistent; a loop adds two to the degree of the vertex.

Comment: This also does not include hypergraphs.

Comment: @Joffan But loops are not directed edges. Undirected edges have incidences from the power set of $V$, right?

Comment: An edge on an undirected graph can be thought of as a set of size two drawn from elements of $V$; to allow loops that would have to be changed to a multiset. Just like the edges $E$ is a set of such sets, but to allow multiple edges (a multigraph) that too would become a multiset. Then you get into directed graphs as mentioned, weighted graphs, edge- and vertex-coloured graphs, all sorts of fancy ways forward.